# Interact with every 2nd, 3rd, and 4th element of a vector until end of vecotr

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a vector of strings that each contain a 4 letter string. The exact number of strings in the vector can change depending on input but the total number of characters of all the strings will always add up to a multiple of 16 (e.g. 64 and 784). Let's say for n vectors I want to access every 2nd, 3rd, and 4th element of the vector, skipping the 1st, 5th, 9th, 13th, etc. elements in the vector. What is the best way to write a loop or function that allows me to interact and edit these strings in the vectors using C++?

Comment: Apply appropriate modulo calculation for the wanted index numbers??

Comment: Note: It is always best to ask a "How do I do?" question with some manner of "Here's what I did so far". A much more useful answer can be based around the attempt showing you here it went wrong and explaining how to avoid similar problems in the future. Plus it is the attempt at solving the problem that often separates your question from the begging hordes who expect Stack Overflow to do their homework for them, so don't underestimate the social importance of showing your work.

Comment: *What is the best way to write a loop* -- There is no "best way".  There are good ways, bad ways, or in-between.  Saying "what is the best way" leads your question to be opinion-based, which is off-topic.  Better to write code first and show us, so we can get a better picture of what you have done, and thus can gear an answer that is similar to what you've attempted.

Comment: Please include an example (as code) of such a vector, along with the subset of the vector you want to extract.

Comment: Use a `for` loop, and increment the index by 4.

Comment: "The **best** way to write..." is usually by using an IDE.  Although some people like me, still favor the Editor & Command line approach (usually for smaller programs).

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
     for(int i = 0; i< svec.size(); i++){
        if(i%4!=0){
            // process string here
            noodleOn(svec[i]);
        }
     }
```

assuming by '1st' you mean - 'the one with index 0' etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a loop that increases an index by 4 every iteration. How you set the initial index value depends on what you find most easy to reason about when asked *"what about if the vector happens to contain a number of strings that is not divisible by 4*"?

I find this easy to reason about:

- Start with the index at the highest index of the first 4 you are going to pick. That is `3`.
- Use the subscript operator with that index and subtract `2`, `1` and `0` to pick the second, third and fourth element.
- Finally step the index by 4.

For me this makes it clear that it'll never access the vector out of bounds:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void interact(const std::string& x2, const std::string& x3, const std::string& x4) {
    std::cout << x2 << ',' << x3 << ',' << x4 << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vs{"Hello", "world", "This", "is",
                                "fun",   "don't", "you",  "think"};

    for (size_t idx = 3; idx < vs.size(); idx += 4) {
        interact(vs[idx - 2], vs[idx - 1], vs[idx - 0]);
        //            2nd          3rd          4th
    }
}
```

Output:

```
world,This,is
don't,you,think
```